# Can't create handler inside thread Thread[PlayBillingLibrary-4,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-billing

```
W/BillingClient: Error consuming purchase!
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[PlayBillingLibrary-4,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:227)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:129)
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:133)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:214)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:1130)
        at com.zenisoft.dishcontroller.ui.home.HomeFragment.CallThanksDialog(HomeFragment.java:423)
        at com.zenisoft.dishcontroller.ui.home.HomeFragment$5.onConsumeResponse(HomeFragment.java:390)
        at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.zzl(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.0.0:14)
        at com.android.billingclient.api.zzu.call(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Я пытаюсь имплементировать Google Billing Library версии 5.0.0

Код:
https://pastebin.com/tdFk4DfA

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Перенесите вызов диалога в главный поток